# SwiftUI Drawing View multiple times

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a JournalView which displays a ScrollView-VStack list of events. Whenever a new event item is added to the list it ends up drawing the view multiple times.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct JournalView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dailyData: DailyData

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                    dailyEventsView()
                        .visibility(!showAddEventsMenu)

                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        AddEventsMenuButton()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func dailyEventsView() -> some View {
        return ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                ForEach(dailyData.events) { event in
                    switch event.type {
                    case .WATER:
                        WaterCardView(eventID: event.id, dailyData: dailyData)

                    default:
                        HStack {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private func AddEventsMenuButton() -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            dailyData.addEvent(event: Event(type: .WATER))
        }){
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .gradientForeground(colors: [.yellow, .orange, .red])
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the DailyData.swift file looks like

```
import SwiftUI

class DailyData: ObservableObject {
    private let TAG: String = "\(DailyData.self)"

    @Published var events: [Event] = []


    public func addEvent(event: Event) {

        Log.d(tag: TAG, msg: "addEvent(event = \(event.id))")

        let index = eventIndex(eventID: event.id)
        if index == -1 {
            Log.d(tag: TAG, msg: "No previous index, adding...")

            // Selection sort insert based on date/time.
            if 0 == events.count {
                Log.d(tag: TAG, msg: "No previous events, adding at index zero.")
                events.append(event)
            } else {
                for i in 0 ..< events.count {
                    if event.dateTime >= events[i].dateTime {
                        events.insert(event, at: i + 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d(tag: TAG, msg: "WaterMacroProgress = \(macroWaterProgress)")
    }

    public func eventIndex(eventID: String) -> Int {
        for i in 0 ..< events.count {
            if eventID == events[i].id {
                return i
            }
        }
        return -1
    }
}
```

When you add the first two events, everything is all good, but then once I started to add the third even and so forth it starts to draw the view multiple times...

This is the output of pressing the "add" button THREE times:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer! After adding in the Event I never break out of the loop!